# If statements not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image]

The questions are being asked but the if statements do not show up. What mistake am I making?

Comment: Do not post code as images, but as text. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Comment: And don't ever, ever use as a variable name a built-in procedure! you're overwriting the `print` function with some bogus values!

Answer (score 2):

`print()` is a built-in function, if you want to call the function to print out text in the console, you have to use it like this:

```
print(arguments)
```

This

```
print = (arguments)
```

is not calling `print()`, but is assigning something to the name "print".